# Numbering rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with the numbering rows in SQL. I have a table:

```
loeid   loe_logid  loe_gidn  lp     ZGNumerloe
----------------------------------------------
76284   5136       198570     1          9820
76285   5136       198571     2          9820
76286   5136       198572     3          9820
76287   5136       198573     4          9820
76288   5136       198574     5          2804
76289   5136       198575     6          2804
76290   5136       198576     7          9294
```

I need to be numbered rows of the column `ZGNumerloe`.

```
loeid   loe_logid  loe_gidn  lp     ZGNumerloe  rank
----------------------------------------------------
76284   5136       198570     1          9820    1
76285   5136       198571     2          9820    1
76286   5136       198572     3          9820    1
76287   5136       198573     4          9820    1
76288   5136       198574     5          2804    2
76289   5136       198575     6          2804    2
76290   5136       198576     7          9294    3
```

I used function `DENSE_RANK` but unnecessarily sort my report.

Comment: Post the code you tried with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full working example:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
     [loeid] INT
    ,[loe_logid] INT
    ,[loe_gidn] INT
    ,[lp] TINYINT
    ,[ZGNumerloe] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([loeid], [loe_logid], [loe_gidn], [lp], [ZGNumerloe])
VALUES (76284, 5136, 198570, 1, 98201)
      ,(76285, 5136, 198571, 2, 98201)
      ,(76286, 5136, 198572, 3, 98201)
      ,(76287, 5136, 198573, 4, 98201)
      ,(76288, 5136, 198574, 5, 28042)
      ,(76289, 5136, 198575, 6, 28042)
      ,(76290, 5136, 198576, 7, 92943);

WITH DataSource ([loeid], [loe_logid], [loe_gidn], [lp], [ZGNumerloe], [MinLPForZG]) AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,MIN([LP]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ZGNumerloe])
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT [loeid]
      ,[loe_logid]
      ,[loe_gidn]
      ,[lp]
      ,[ZGNumerloe]
      ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [MinLPForZG])
FROM DataSource;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This sentence *but unnecessarily sort my report* makes me think, that you might not be aware of some principles of sorting.

- There is **no implicit sort order** in your resultset.
- There is **only one way to guarantee the sort order**: An `ORDER BY` on the  outermost `SELECT`
- If your report was sorted the way you need it, and after using `DENSE_RANK` it isn't anymore, **you were just lucky**
- Sorting the result-set is the **expected behaviour** of functions using `OVER(ORDER BY...)`
- Look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825(v=sql.90).aspx) at *Examples*:

You find there

> Notice that the ORDER BY in the OVER clause orders the DENSE_RANK and the ORDER BY of the SELECT statement orders the result set.

### UPDATE

This sentence *I need to be numbered rows of the column ZGNumerloe* makes me think, that you eventually are looking for this

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ZGNumerloe ORDER BY lp) AS PartitionedNumber
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select *, row_number () over (partition by loeid,loe_gidn order by lp asc) as rnk from Yourtable
```

Comment: Please explain what the problem was with the asker's code and explain you code. Code-only answers is frown upon.

Comment: have you test your code? Your code always give 1 in rnk column

Answer (score -1):

Very simple need to use dense_rank function.

```
SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER  BY [ZGNUMERLOE] DESC) Rnk FROM #TABLE1
```

Comment: I don't know why people are not adding comment when they voted down.